# Xml file reading by its node c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, webforms

I want to read a XML file and then show it to the webpage but I am unable to do it in for loop

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:/xmldatabase.xml");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//User");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Label1.Text = node["Name"].InnerText;
    Label3.Text = node["Contact"].InnerText;
    Label4.Text = node["Email"].InnerText;
    Label2.Text = node["City"].InnerText;
    Label5.Text = node["Country"].InnerText;
}
```

My XML having data!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<User-Profile>
  <User>
    <Name>Jhon</Name>
    <Contact>4567897632</Contact>
    <Email>pri@dfdcm.com</Email>
    <City>xyz</City>
    <Country>abc</Country>
  </User>
    <User>
    <Name>Mike</Name>
    <Contact>8888888</Contact>
    <Email>acvb@dfdcm.com</Email>
    <City>xrtty</City>
    <Country>abffff</Country>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Name>Stone</Name>
    <Contact>875467</Contact>
    <Email>dfttgh@dfdcm.com</Email>
    <City>dfvbnj</City>
    <Country>ddccvv</Country>
  </User>
</User-Profile>
```

I want to show all data using loop or any thing and assign these data to my webpage labels is it possible? How to do this?

Comment: Any reason not to use LINQ to XML? It's likely to make everything much simpler...

Comment: i dont know about LINQ to XML if it is easy can you show me the sample of my case reading the xml and printing the whole result in webpage labels

Comment: LINQ is the best option, and much easier, but in your code you will probably be showing the values of the last iteration in your labels. If you have to display the records in labels, you should create them inside the loop and add them to the web page

Comment: What error are you seeing? Where is the program crashing? What's not working?

Comment: Well, even if you have 10'000 nodes for `//Users` - you keep setting the `.Text` values for those fixed 5 labels, over and over and over again...... what you need to change is **how to show** the data (the reading is fine) - you need a listbox or a listview or a grid or something that can show a list of data - not just five fixed labels for one set of texts

Comment: @marc_s exactly that is my concern how to show the data on fixed 5 labels i dont know much about more can you suggest the simplest way i have only 10-15 data records for Users on XML file i want to show them on webpage how could i do this ?

Comment: @smita: if you have five fixed labels - one for each property of your nodes. You **CANNOT** show data from multiple nodes on just five labels - that'll never work! You need some kind of a list-based display mechanism....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use "PlaceHolder" in c#.you can easily drag and drop PlaceHolder :)
then use this code

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
  PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table><tr><td>" + node["Name"].InnerText + "</td><td>"+node["Contact"].InnerText+"</td><td>"+node["Email"].InnerText+"</td><td>"+node["City"].InnerText+"</td><td>"+node["Country"].InnerText+"</td></tr></tabel>")); 
}
```

Important :-
Some text are missing above code.please compare with below image.then you can develop best code. :) [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUQds.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is use a Repeater. Then you can in your foreach loop add every User a List, and populate your repeater with that list. For more info on repeaters and how to populate them, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx.